# Use Java Reflections on external JAR file during Maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, reflection, jar

I want to use Reflections to select all classes that have a specific Annotation on them from a JAR file that gets created during a Maven build but I think I am running into an issue to do with the files not being in the classpath since the JAR is create during the Maven build and then my code is also run by Maven but I'm not sure if this is correct OR if it is the issue how to go about fixing it.

When testing my code I just run the file directly in Eclipse and it seems to read the JAR and find the classes ok but when the file is called during a Maven build after the JAR is created I get ClassNotFoundExceptions for each class.
This is the code block where I am specifying the JAR file and trying to use Reflections to find the classes in a specific module:

```
    webClasses = new URL("jar", "","file:" + "C:/
development/workspaces/trunk/target/created.jar/!/classes/myModule/");
    URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { webClasses });
    reflections = new Reflections(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(cl), new TypeAnnotationsScanner(), cl);
```

Hopefully I explained that ok, should it be possible to call Reflections on a JAR file from a Maven build and for it to actually work?

**EDIT**

The reason for doing this is that we need to generically extract some information from certain classes regarding validation information using reflection and create a JSON file with that info that will be used by a different system. I am not doing anything with the JAR that is created, it is just being used to try and extract the info because we will need this JSON file create with every build of the JAR.

Comment: This makes no sense to me at all.  Why do you think you have to select classes?  Build the JAR with all the classes and let the class loader bring in the ones it needs at runtime.  No need for you to do anything special.

Comment: @duffymo I am not using the JAR I am trying to generically extract some information from certain classes using reflection and create a JSON file with that info that will be used by a different system. I'll update the post with more info

Comment: Makes no sense to me.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that while the maven build is being done I can access the package names so I don't need to access the JAR file at all so I can just use the following line instead:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.myPackage1.myPackage2");
```